# Newbie - creating drop down lists x 2 and writing the code. - Ambiguous name detected

Tags: excel, dropdown

I have made 2 drop down lists which have a name and then a value in the column next to it.
eg.

| col 1 | col b |
| --- | --- |
| Tier 1 | 0 |
| Tier 2 | 0.2 |

And then

| col 1 | col b |
| --- | --- |
| AMP | 0.693 |
| ANZ | 0.715 |

I found the below code to use and I have changed the target columns as directed and the dropdown name.

But I keep getting an ambiguous name detected. I think the code I am using is only for 1 drop down list per work sheet. It works when I have it on different sheets single use only.

I did want to have my drop down lists on sheets at the rear of the book and simply copy the dropdown into other cells on previous sheets, but I couldn't figure that out on google.

Please assist with code or how to insert a dropdown from another sheet. You help is greatly appreciated :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice
    selectedNa = Target.Value
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("tier"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice
    selectedNa = Target.Value
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("comm"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only have *one* `Worksheet_Change` handler. So all relevant code needs combined into just one subroutine.

Comment: In the first Sub replace the last `End If` with the `If....End if` block from the second sub and change that `if` to `elseif`. Then delete the second sub. Think that should do it

Comment: Hi BigBen and Darren, thank you for the advice, but I don't understand what either have you have advised to do (SORRY). I've never written code, this was taken from a web page. What's a second sub? how would I change other relevant code? Thanks!